# The type or namespace name 'DataSource' could not be found

Tags: java, c#, .net, weka, ikvm

I am using weka API through C#. I have converted weka jar file to C# DLL by using ikvm. Then I have added the converted DLL (wekacsharp.dll) in my reference.

I have also added ikvm.gnu.classpath.dll, IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll, IKVM.OpenJDK.Util.dll, IKVM.OpenJDK.Text.dll, IKVM.OpenJDK.Core in my reference.

I am trying to use j48 algorithm but I am getting the error. Screen shot of code error is attached. Kindly check it and suggest something to fix it.

```
            J48 J48_tree = new J48(); //Creating J48 tree instance
            DataSource data_source = new DataSource("iris.arff");         
            Instances data = data_source.getDataSet();        
            if (data.classIndex() == -1)            
                data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

            J48_tree.buildClassifier(data); // Builds the classifier   

            javax.swing.JFrame j_frame = new javax.swing.JFrame("J48 Tree");

            //final javax.swing.JFrame j_frame = new javax.swing.JFrame("J48 Tree");        
            j_frame.setSize(1200,700);      
            j_frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            TreeVisualizer tree_visualizer = new TreeVisualizer(null, J48_tree.graph(), new PlaceNode2());      
            j_frame.getContentPane().add(tree_visualizer, BorderLayout.CENTER);    

            j_frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {j_frame.dispose(); }});

            j_frame.setVisible(true);
            tree_visualizer.fitToScreen();
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: As some of the errors state : _are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?_, i.e have you used the [using keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) to import those dll files into the project?

Comment: I am trying to add these namespaces :
using java.awt.BorderLayout;
using weka.core.Instances;
using weka.gui.treevisualizer.PlaceNode2;
using weka.gui.treevisualizer.TreeVisualizer;
using weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;

But m getting error: a using namespace directive can only be applies to namespaces; 'weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource' is a type not a namespace

Comment: @Maria I believe that you need to convert the relevant JAR files to DLL files so that they can be used in your .NET project. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666613/java-classes-cant-get-the-resources-in-jar-files-that-compiled-with-ikvm